# File is being overwritten in some scenarios

Tags: php, concurrency

I'm working on a system that receives push notifications and handle them by parsing it with XSL template and creating (if it doesn't exist) or appending XML parsed data to a file.
Sometimes it receives several notifications at near same time, so the first notification creates the file, but second one creates it again because in that moment I think file is being written but does not exist in filesystem yet. So the result is first xml data is lost by being overwriten by second call to script.

I think the main problem is when trying to scan_dir in order to check if file already exists. First call does not find the file (correct), but second call can't find the file because first call is writting the file in that moment. I have no way to determine the file name so I must apply the regex pattern, because don't know when file, if it was, was created. Initially I used glob with same results, so changed to scan_dir because I think scan_dir is faster.

```
/**
 * Main method
 * @return string XML resulting
 */
public function run()
{
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($this->xml);
    $xsl = new \DOMDocument();
    $xsl->load(self::XSLPATH);

    // Transformer config
    $proc = new \XSLTProcessor;
    $proc->registerPHPFunctions();
    $proc->importStyleSheet($xsl);

    $xmlResult = $proc->transformToXML($xml);

    //  Obtain path to destination folder
    $path = self::PATH."/{$this->folder}/";
    //  Get the file with pattern
    $file_list = glob($path."fileoutput*.xml");


    //  If there exists files matching the pattern, get the first one
    if (sizeof($file_list) > 0) {
        $this->append($xmlResult, $file_list[0]);
    } else {
        // ERROR! concurrent calls end here beceause file is not 
        // in filesystem so scan_dir can't detect it!
        $filename = "fileoutput_".date("d-m-Y_H-i-s").".xml";
        $this->writeFile(
            __DIR__."/../../../output/{$this->folder}/{$filename}",
            $xmlResult
        );
    }

    //  return the xml string
    return $xmlResult;
}

/**
 * This method uses flock to gain exclusive acces to resource.
 * 
 * @param string $filepath file path
 * @param string $data dat ato be written
 * @return void
 */
private function writeFile($filepath, $data)
{
    $fh = fopen($filepath, "w");
    $tries = 5;

    while ($tries > 0) {
        $locked = flock($fh, LOCK_EX);
        if (! $locked) {
            sleep(5);
            $tries--;
        } else {
            $tries = 0;
        }
    }

    if ($locked) {
        fwrite($fh, $data);
        flock($fh, LOCK_UN);
    }

    fclose($fh);
}

/**
 * Append xml data to existing xml
 * @param $xml string xml to append
 * @param $file string file where xml will be append
 */
private function append($xml, $filename)
{
    $xmlFromFile = simplexml_load_file($filename);
    $xmlToAppend = simplexml_load_string($xml);

    $nodeToAppend = $xmlToAppend->reserva;
    $this->sxml_append($xmlFromFile, $nodeToAppend);

    $this->writeFile($filename, $xmlFromFile->asXML());

}

/**
 * This method adds a childnode to xml with deep copy
 * @param $to SimpleXMLElement xml where childnode is copied
 * @param $from SimpleXMLElement xml childnode to copy to
 * @return void
 */
private function sxml_append(\SimpleXMLElement $to, \SimpleXMLElement $from)
{
    $toDom = dom_import_simplexml($to);
    $fromDom = dom_import_simplexml($from);

    $toDom->formatOutput = true;
    //$toDom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

    $toDom->appendChild($toDom->ownerDocument->createTextNode("\n"));   
    $toDom->appendChild($toDom->ownerDocument->importNode($fromDom, true));
}
```

What I'm trying is to handle all notifications data to file even when they reach my script near same time. If I receive 2 notifications near same time, I need all the data without overwriting it.

Comment: [`flock()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php)

Comment: @RiggsFolly already using it, but the problem is when trying to check if there's a previous file. First call does not find the file (that is correct) so it creates it using flock. Second call is unable to check if file  exist via scan_dir because is being writen in that exact moment so does not exist yet in filesystem. I need to use scan_dir or glob because there's no way to know the file name, this is a requirement, file name pattern is fileoutput_date_time.xml so no way to know the exact name, I must check if there exist a file with that pattern.

Comment: So dont lock the actual file. Create a `lock.dat` file. Only update the real file if you can geta  lock on the lock file

Comment: @RiggsFolly It did the trick, thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [RiggsFolly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2310830/riggsfolly) suggested, if I create a **lock.dat** file and try to get a lock on it, I'll be able to write or get in a safe way the output file avoiding the overwriting of data.

I attach the modified code. Tried with [jMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/), made 5 concurrent calls to PHP script with success!

```
/**
 * Main method
 * @return string XML resulting
 */
public function run()
{
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($this->xml);
    $xsl = new \DOMDocument();
    $xsl->load(self::XSLPATH);

    // Transformer config
    $proc = new \XSLTProcessor;
    $proc->registerPHPFunctions();
    $proc->importStyleSheet($xsl);

    $xmlResult = $proc->transformToXML($xml);

    //  Obtain path to destination folder
    $path = self::PATH."/{$this->folder}/";
    //  Get the file with pattern
    $file_list = glob($path."fileoutput*.xml");

    $lockfile = fopen("lock.dat", "w");

    //  check if get lock for $lockfile
    if($this->getLock($lockfile)) {
        $file_list = glob($path."fileoutput*.xml");

        //  If there exist files matching the pattern, get the first one
        if (sizeof($file_list) > 0) {
            $this->append($xmlResult, $file_list[0]);
        } else {
            //NICE! now it is sure we create file only when got lock in $lockfile,
            //so it won't be overwriten
            $filename = "fileoutput_".date("d-m-Y_H-i-s").".xml";
            $this->writeFile(__DIR__."/../../../output/{$this->folder}/{$filename}", $xmlResult);
        }

    }

    //  return the xml string
    return $xmlResult;
}

/**
* this method tries to get lock on a file
* @param resource $file The lock file
*
* @return boolean true if we get lock, false if not
*/
private function getLock($file)
    {
        $fh = $file;
        $tries = 5;

        while ($tries > 0) {
            $locked = flock($fh, LOCK_EX);

            if (! $locked) {
                sleep(5);
                $tries--;
            } else {
                $tries = 0;
            }
        }

        return $locked;
    }

/**
 * This method uses flock to gain exclusive acces to resource.
 * 
 * @param string $filepath file path
 * @param string $data dat ato be written
 * @return void
 */
private function writeFile($filepath, $data)
{
    $fh = fopen($filepath, "w");
    $tries = 5;

    while ($tries > 0) {
        $locked = flock($fh, LOCK_EX);
        if (! $locked) {
            sleep(5);
            $tries--;
        } else {
            $tries = 0;
        }
    }

    if ($locked) {
        fwrite($fh, $data);
        flock($fh, LOCK_UN);
    }

    fclose($fh);
}

/**
 * Append xml data to existing xml
 * @param $xml string xml to append
 * @param $file string file where xml will be append
 */
private function append($xml, $filename)
{
    $xmlFromFile = simplexml_load_file($filename);
    $xmlToAppend = simplexml_load_string($xml);

    $nodeToAppend = $xmlToAppend->reserva;
    $this->sxml_append($xmlFromFile, $nodeToAppend);

    $this->writeFile($filename, $xmlFromFile->asXML());

}

/**
 * This method adds a childnode to xml with deep copy
 * @param $to SimpleXMLElement xml where childnode is copied
 * @param $from SimpleXMLElement xml childnode to copy to
 * @return void
 */
private function sxml_append(\SimpleXMLElement $to, \SimpleXMLElement $from)
{
    $toDom = dom_import_simplexml($to);
    $fromDom = dom_import_simplexml($from);

    $toDom->formatOutput = true;
    //$toDom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

    $toDom->appendChild($toDom->ownerDocument->createTextNode("\n"));   
    $toDom->appendChild($toDom->ownerDocument->importNode($fromDom, true));
}
```